# Adding a Table of Contents to the ACM style template

Tags: table-of-contents, acm

I have been instructed to use the [ACM style](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sigguide-v2.2sp) latex template for an assignment. In the [.cls file](http://semanticweb.cs.vu.nl/KM2011/Files/acm_proc_10ptArticle-sp.cls) they provide, I can find the following warning:

> %%% 4)  Marginal paragraphs, tables of contents, lists of figures and tables,
>
> %%%     and page headings are all forbidden.

Even though we have been instructed to use the ACM template, however silly it may be, we are required to insert a table of contents.

I attempt to add `\tableofcontents` as follows:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_10ptArticle-sp}
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
Lipsum
\section{Conclusion}
Lipsum
\end{document}
```

When I compile, I receive the following error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@latexerr #1#2->\GenericError 
                              {\space \space \space \@spaces  \@spaces \@spa...
l.38 \tableofcontents

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

Additionally, i find the following section in the `.cls` file:

```
\def\tableofcontents{\@latexerr{\tableofcontents: Tables of contents are not
 allowed in the `acmconf' document style.}\@eha}
```

I was hoping to find a solution for this without having to use a different template file. Is there anything I can do to add a table of contents regardless of their warning?

Comment: Do you have some code for us to work on? Please post it.

Comment: This is the .cls file we've been instructed to use, followed by the example .tex file we were given. Does that help?
http://semanticweb.cs.vu.nl/KM2011/Files/acm_proc_10ptArticle-sp.cls

http://semanticweb.cs.vu.nl/KM2011/Files/sigproc-sample.tex

Comment: We need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so that we need not try to recreate the scenario.

Comment: BTW, Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks Harish, I have updated to reflect hopefully as much information as I can. I did not create the .cls file myself, so I would not know where to look if that is what I need to modify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.cls` file you provided defines `\tableofcontents` to produce an error message (the class designers really wanted to discourage producing a ToC):

```
\def\tableofcontents{\@latexerr{\tableofcontents: Tables of contents are not
  allowed in the `acmconf' document style.}\@eha}
```

You can override this by providing (in your `.tex` file) a sensible definition for `\tableofcontents`; something along the lines

```
\def\contentsname{Contents}
\def\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_10ptArticle-sp}

\makeatletter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\def\contentsname{Contents}
\def\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
Lipsum
\section{Conclusion}
Lipsum

\end{document}
```

The result, showing the generated ToC:

[image]

Comment: This was it! So simple. Thank you! I would upvote, but it seems I don't have enough reputation.